# Max and min both in a Group BY

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have requirement where I need to pull Max of data when > 0 and Min of data when < 0. And the tricky part is it should be in a same column. Example as follows: 
Below Query:

```
SELECT A.employee_id, paycheck_number
      max ( CASE 
           WHEN B.special = 'XXT' THEN B.AMOUNT
           ELSE 0 
         END ) AMOUNT, 
       max ( CASE 
           WHEN B.special = 'XXH' THEN B.hrs1
           ELSE 0 
         END ) HRS1
FROM   Table1 A, 
       table2 B 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 C 
                    ON B.company = C.company 
WHERE  A .employee_id = '123456789' 
GROUP  BY A.employee_id, paycheck_number 
ORDER  BY 1
```

Returns:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID   AMOUNT     HRS1     paycheck_number
123456789     2799.82    134.84   1234
123456789     832.86     40       4321
123456789     0          0        5678
```

If removed the group by the data is :

```
EMPLOYEE_ID   AMOUNT     HRS1     paycheck_number
123456789     0          134.84   1234
123456789     2799.82    0        1234
123456789     0          40       4321
123456789     832.86     0        4321
123456789     0          -40      5678
123456789     -832.86    0        5678
```

Whereas I want:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID   AMOUNT     HRS1     paycheck_number
123456789     2799.82    134.84   1234
123456789     832.86     40       4321
123456789     -832.86    -40      5678
```

It looks simple but when I try It doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post some sample input data..

Comment: @Teja: Input data?

Comment: What do you have in all three tables.

Comment: Pls post it in your question

Comment: @Developer that is great, now please copy it from the Comment, add it to your Original Post so it can be formatted (and then you can delete the Comment). Such additional info belongs in the post, not a comment.

Comment: So - it seems the rows are grouped by `paycheck_number` - that info should appear in the output too (I assume). Then, for a given paycheck, within each column (Amount and HRS1, apparently), is it guaranteed that EITHER all the values are >= 0, OR all the values are <= 0? And what's the deal with HRS2 - you show they are all either 0 or NULL. (If we are to refer to your attempted query - what is the `special` column? It's not shown in your test input data.)

Comment: You are showing a query grouped by employee_id. Then you show it's result with three rows all for the same employee_id. How can that be? And are you sure you want to cross join tabkes A and B? That has your results completely unrelated to the employee_id. And why does`n't your query result in an error when you are accessing fileds that are neither part of the group nor aggregated? Please correct this query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The query was too long, that's y I trimmed it and shown only relevant query. Please check my last data sample where I have shown you it's grouped by emplid and paycheck_number.

Comment: @mathguy your question "is it guaranteed that EITHER all the values are >= 0, OR all the values are <= 0? " NO, that's y I want a check like if >0 then max and if  <0 then min. This is what actually causing the issue and makes query complicated.

Comment: Well, unfortunately you have mutilated your query, so it makes no sense. It makes your question hard to answer, because you show things that cannot be. Now you say you used `min` or `max` in your query. Maybe you want it to be `sum` instead?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner check the query now it's currently exactly how it is. So as you see it picks only max for amount and hrs1 which means it will pick 0 for row three which is true because I'm using max. but I want something some trick which will make it pick negative value when it's <0 and positive when >0. In other words if >0 then max else if <0 then min. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Well, the `group by` clause still doesn't match the results shown. However, doesn't the answer I posted solve your issue?

Comment: And by the way, *are* there actually records with zero values or are you creating all Zeros yourself with `ELSE 0`? In that case, you can simply remove the else branch, so you get null, which is not considered in `min`, `max` and `sum`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I made the query more specific to my requirement can you please check?

Comment: It's your turn to check actually. Have you understood all I've said? Have you understood my answer? Have you understood why it is maybe `sum` you want to apply instead of `max`? Have you understood that removing the else branches alone might already solve your issues? Have you tried `keep first/last`? Come back when you have read and studied and applied all this and all the suggestions don't solve your problem. (In which case you would have to show sample data and information where the given techniques fail. Maybe even add a fiddle in sqlfiddle.com.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner okay, I will check. Thank you so much

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Super! Removing the else condition worked. I vaguely remember that adding "else" condition was for a reason but, now removing it did not made any change to my results other than what I wanted. so great, It worked like a charm. Thanks sir! Add in the answer section so that I can mark it as a right answer.

Comment: Okay, glad this works for you. I've added this solution to my answer, so that future readers with the same problem find the solution easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle you get the value for the maximum absolute amount via `KEEP DENSE_RANK FIRST/LAST`:

```
max(value) keep (dense_rank last order by abs(value))
```

However, when there is always only the one non-zero value in one record and zeros or nulls in the other records to consider, you could simply add them:

```
sum(value)
```

In your case where only one record actually contains a value, you are creating the zero entries yourself and thus get 0 instead of, say, -40 when asking for the maximum value. Remove the `ELSE` branches that create the interfering zeros, and `MAX` will get you the correct value. E.g.:

```
max(case when b.special = 'XXT' then b.amount end) as amount
```